# Segmentation fault (core dumped) consequences

Tags: segmentation-fault

If we get the output as segmentation fault core dumped. It describes some intruder action. What will be the consequences when segmentation fault occurs?

Answer (score 1):

It does not describe some intruder action. It means the program tried to access a part of memory (also called a "segment") it has no access to.

Intruders *can* make use of segmentation faults. But the program is at fault and should be fixed.  What the intruder can do with it, depends a lot on the program and under what privileges it runs.

The "core dumped" part means that the program's memory has been dumped to disk for analysis (with tools like [gdb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger)).

More about segmentation faults [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277331/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-to-where-what-is-it-and-why).